# Why can't base type pointer take derived class object's adress value?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, protected

```
class A{
fct1(){}; 
};

class B:public A{
fct2(){};  
};
// B b; 
// A* a = &b; good! possible!!

class A{
fct1(){}; 
};
class B:protected A{
fct2(){};  
};
//B b;
// A* a=&b; error!
```

why is that?

What does protected inheritance have to do with pointer?

I learned that protected inheritance changes public area to protected area, so that only derived class can access its member functions and variables. :(

Please explain the principle and reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of *access control* is to ... control who gets access to which parts of a class. "Protected" means that only derived classes have access.

The access level on a base class determines access to the base subobject. Putting this together, this means that only derived classes have access to protected base subobjects. So the conversion of `&b` to a pointer to `A` is not allowed outside classes derived from `A`.

Comment: Then I can't build polymorphism with protected inheritance?

Comment: and does subobject mean something like fct1 in class? I learned C++ in Korean :P

Comment: "Polymorphism" is a dangerously vague word. Usually, "dynamic polymorphism" (or "virtual-function polymorphism") refers to **public** inheritance. In that interpretation of polymorphism, you want to treat a `B` *as if* it was an `A`, so the base subobject must be public.